# Alt+Enter in JetBrains GoLand doesn't show options to import at all

Tags: jetbrains-ide, goland

I'm using GoLand and for some reason it is ambiguous to me, if I use a package that is not imported by typing the package name, GoLand doesn't import it in Auto import tab in settings.I checked all boxes. Even when I press <kbd>Alt + Enter</kbd> to some packages that is not yet imported, it doesn't show any error or suggestion, just can not find declaration to .... . What should I do?

Comment: Give an example of what package you are trying to import. Is it a standard one? If not have you used "go get" (or go modules) to get it?  Also Go auto import settings are under File/Settings/Go/Imports not File/Settings/Editor/General/Auto Import.
BTW This (like your previous question) has nothing to do with the Go language per se, and will annoy people looking for Go questions who do not use GoLand - just using goland keyword is sufficient.

Comment: For example I use gorm.Open("sqlite3", "test.db") method without first importing it(I installed the package via 'go get ...'). It does not auto import required package and I have to add it manually. Also I checked  File/Settings/Go/Imports. I saw all the check boxes checked.